# How can I remove 'Windows' folder in network locations on nautilus?

Tags: networking, windows, nautilus

I use a fresh install of Ubuntu GNOME 16.04. How can I remove the Windows folder in network locations? I don't want to share anything with my Windows PC, so I want to remove that connection.

[image: look_image_please]

Comment: Not a connection, doesn't need to be removed and it cannot share anything *per se*.